# How to stop water seaping inbetween concrete slabs

Tags: concrete

I have two slabs in a Home Office converted from a garage.

The regular garage slab and another which is about 6 inch higher than the garage one. The lower one has a wall between the two except for a large door. This wall is seated on a 2x4 timber planks.

When there is very heavy rain, water seeps under that timber in the doorway into the lower garage floor.

I see it seeping in and wondered how I could stop it.

We are on a slight slope down toward the office and have clay just one meter below. I guess it is the water preessure below that is causing it.

Thanks.

oz

Comment: Is it possible to get a picture please?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, most likely that is water pressure causing it. Ideally, you'd install a drain tile system with sump pump to pump the water elsewhere, essentially redirecting the water. That is a very labor intensive and expensive task to complete, due to the labor involved. It does work very well, though.

I've seen people get away with sealing the joint well with something like Sikaflex. The issue there is you're simply impeding the pressure being relieved. It will either find another spot to relieve pressure (and hopefully not inside your office), or will push it's way through whatever sealant you use.

Comment: The water doesn't _have_ to come thru somewhere else; it could simply flow past the house as if the basement was a large rock. I grant that it often seems like plugging one spot just exposes another, but sealing things up isn't completely impossible. Having said that, yes, french drains into a sump and pumping from there is one of the more reliable, if less elegant, solutions.